# Hidden/show image scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

Seeing that effect

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0){
    $('.a').fadeOut();
  }
  else {
    $('.a').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

link:  http://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/239/

how can I start that with my image hidden and show with the scroll?

I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By changing to

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.a').fadeIn();
  }
  else {
    $('.a').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

and setting `display:none;` to `a`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xc8hg3do/)

Comment: @Kolby Thanks for your concerns. As I understood the OP, question was just how to reverse the effect. If anything else is intended by OP he'll maybe update the question.

Comment: Thank you Mathias, actually you understood right my trouble. I tried this operation. Hidden when certain point of the site and show when scrolling, turning back to hidden when returns to that point . Reading my own question maybe I couldn't explain exactly how I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/1834/

First set the display to

> display: none;

in your css.

Then when you scroll fadeIn.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.a').fadeIn();
});
```

So to optimize this a little better there's a few things we can do.
First, every time you call $(); it's running a function. We can prevent this function from being called every time you scroll by defining `a` outside the scroll function.

```
var a = $('.a');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    a.fadeIn();
});
```

Second, we don't want to run fadeIn() every time we scroll, because after the first time the user scrolls it's going to be visible. What we can do is unbind the scroll event.

```
var win = $(window);
var a = $('.a');

win.on('scroll', function() {
    a.fadeIn();
    win.off('scroll');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/1835/

Comment: thanks Kolby, I tried put display: none before in my CSS, but I couldn't make this works right in the script.